# C++ project in visual studio 2017 using ANTLR4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, antlr4

I have a working project in c# using antlr4 from which I can create a package to be used in other projects (via a NuGet package, or referencing the .dll). I'm trying to recreate the same project in c++ but I can't get even a basic project working. In the c# project, I could simply add the grammars using "add new item", but I can't in a fresh c++ project. I've been searching a bit on the internet and tried the following:

Firstly, the [demo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Cpp/demo) from the antlr4 github repo.
Using vs 2017 and antlr v4.12.0, I can run the generation, open the solution, but not compile, as I get the following error when trying to build:
[build tools error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZSQr.png), which I'm pretty sure comes from have an older visual studio version.

Second thing I tried comes from [here](https://beyondtheloop.dev/Antlr-cpp-cmake/) ([associated repository](https://github.com/blorente/antlr-4.7-cpp-cmake-base)), from which I can run `cmake`, which generates a [build directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf24F.png), but doesn't generate the lexer/parser, and any cpp file trying to `#include "antlr-runtime.h"` fails to find it.

Last thing I tried was going to [this older commit of the antlr repo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/0172e8661f97544627c74a65ae9f8cf8994e6afb/runtime/Cpp/cmake). Which gave me the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lP1h.png) when trying to build, which are probably due to the company's proxy blocking downloads.

Having tried all this, I still have no working c++ project in vs 2017 in which I can use the grammars I wrote. In the official c++ target readme, it says

> Compiling on Windows with Visual Studio using he Visual Studio projects
>
> Simply open the VS project from the runtime folder (VS 2019+) and build it.
>
> Compiling on Windows using cmake with Visual Studio VS2019 and later
>
> Use the "Open Folder" Feature from the File->Open->Folder menu to open the runtime/Cpp directory. It will automatically use the CMake description to open up a Visual Studio Solution.

From which I assume I could get it working with vs 2019/2022 but I can't (at least for now) install it. Is there no way to have a working antlr4 project in vs 2017?

Answer (score 0):

> The build tools for v143:

You need to specify v141 (VS2017 build tools) in the properties of the project. In addition, Windows SDK 10 needs to be specified.

[image]